# Wrote my function and the testing code but still receiving typeError

Tags: javascript

I was tasked to write my own testing code for a prompt and then write the corresponding function to run the code correctly, I have done that but for some reason when I run it, it comes back as a typeError saying that my function isn't a function or it is not iterable.

This is the prompt I am given for writing my function:

Complete the function partitionStudentsByScore(). This function takes an array of students and a specific score and returns an array of two arrays. Separate the students so that any student with a score equal to or less than the given score is in the first array and all other students are in the second array.

Here is my function:

```
function partitionStudentsByScore(student, num){
var highScoreStudents = []
var lowScoreStudents = []
for (var i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
    if (student[i].score >= num) {
        highScoreStudents.push(student[i])
    }
    else
        lowScoreStudents.push(student[i])
}
console.log(highScoreStudents)
console.log(lowScoreStudents)
}
module.exports = partitionStudentsByScore;
```

Here is the prompt I am given for writing my testing code:

As you are building the function, write tests for your code in tests/solution.test.js. For example, you will want to at least cover the following cases.

Students are correctly partitioned into their appropriate arrays.
It is possible for all students to go into one of the arrays.
If the student list is empty, return an array of two arrays (e.g. [[], []])

Here is my Testing code that I wrote:

```
const expect = require("chai").expect;
const partitionStudentsByScore = require("../src/solution");
describe("partitionStudentsByScore", () => {
it("should return an array with two arrays containing two groups of student by their score", () => {
const students = [
  { name: "Leo Yeon-Joo", score: 8.9 },
  { name: "Morgan Sutton", score: 7.4 },
  { name: "Natalee Vargas", score: 9.2 },
];
const expected = [
  [{ name: "Morgan Sutton", score: 7.4 }],
  [
    { name: "Leo Yeon-Joo", score: 8.9 },
    { name: "Natalee Vargas", score: 9.2 },
  ],
]; 
const actual = partitionStudentsByScore(students, 8);
expect(actual).to.eql(expected);
const emptyArray = partitionStudentsByScore([], 8);
expect(emptyArray).to.have.lengthOf(2);
expect(emptyArray[0]).to.be.empty;
expect(emptyArray[1]).to.be.empty;
const allStudents = partitionStudentsByScore(students, 10);
expect(allStudents[1]).to.be.empty;
expect(allStudents[0]).to.have.lengthOf(3);
});
});
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: your function doesn't have any return statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are expecting a return value from your function:

```
const actual = partitionStudentsByScore(students, 8);
```

but your function is not returning any value.
add a return statement for `partitionStudentsByScore`

if you want to return the array of arrays add this:

```
 return [highScoreStudents, lowScoreStudents];
```

so your function should look like this:

```
function partitionStudentsByScore(student, num) {
  var highScoreStudents = [];
  var lowScoreStudents = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
    if (student[i].score >= num) {
      highScoreStudents.push(student[i]);
    } else lowScoreStudents.push(student[i]);
  }
  console.log(highScoreStudents);
  console.log(lowScoreStudents);
  return [highScoreStudents, lowScoreStudents];
}
module.exports = partitionStudentsByScore;
```

Comment: I didnt even realize i overlooked putting in a return statement thanks for pointing that out that simplifies everything now haha

Comment: I just had to swap the returns and everything runs perfectly now. Thank you for your help!